# JavaScript virtual pet

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, constructor

I am trying to create a text-based virtual pet care game. I want to be able to give you two pets(Objects with properties) and functions to interact with those objects by modifying the objects properties. So here is what I have:

```
function Pet(pet_name){
    this.pet_name = pet_name;
    this.pet_hunger = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    this.pet_health = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    this.pet_happiness = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    this.feed = feed;
    this.show = show;
}

pet1 = new Pet("Brian");
pet2 = new Pet("Lassy");

function feed(){
    var amount = Math.floor((Math.random() *2) + 1);
    this.pet_hunger = this.pet_hunger - amount;
    if (this.pet_hunger < 0){
        this.pet_hunger = 0;
    }
    this.show();
 }

function show(){
    var the_string = "";
    if (this.pet_health === 0){
        the_string = this.pet_name + " is dead!";
    }
    else {
        the_string += "Name: " + this.pet_name;
        the_string += "Hunger: " + this.pet_name;
        the_string += "Health: " + this.pet_health;
        the_string += "Happiness: " + this.pet_happinesss;
    }
}
```

When I run the code:

```
console.log(pet1);
console.log(pet1.feed());  
console.log(pet1);
```

I receive the following:

```
{ pet_name: 'Brian',
  pet_hunger: 4,
  pet_health: 4,
  pet_happiness: 10,
  feed: [Function: feed],
  show: [Function: show] }
undefined
{ pet_name: 'Brian',
  pet_hunger: 2,
  pet_health: 4,
  pet_happiness: 10,
  feed: [Function: feed],
  show: [Function: show] }
```

So we can see the `feed` function is working. However, I'm still unsure why the undefined shows. Now, I created a function called `show`. This SHOULD show the four man stats(name, hunger, health, happiness). However, when I try to run:

```
console.log(pet1.show);
console.log(pet1.feed());
console.log(pet1);
```

I receive the following:

```
[Function: show]
undefined
{ pet_name: 'Brian',
  pet_hunger: 4,
  pet_health: 1,
  pet_happiness: 9,
  feed: [Function: feed],
  show: [Function: show] }
```

I'm unsure why my `show` function is not working. I really just want my console to show cleanly:
Name:
Hunger:
Health:
Happiness:
Any ideas guys?

Comment: You shouldn't edit a question and replace its content with a new one. Limit yourself to one question per post, then close the question by picking the "best answer". [Read the StackOverflow guide.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

In JavaScript, you have to always place parenthesis to execute a function. Replace `.show` with `.show()`;

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Thanks, I'm new to StackOverflow. I will be sure to close the question. Does it automatically close when best answer has been selected?

Comment: @Nappstir Questions don't "close" but are basically marked as "this solves the problem I was having". Based on the nature of technical questions, the correct/best solution may change over time and alternative (or new) answers may be upvoted/accepted in the future

Answer (score 1):

For example, the feed method could be:

```
function feed(amountOfFood){
  this.hunger += amountOfFood; //Same as this.hunger = this.hunger + amountOfFood;
}
```

You will then presumably have a way in which this method is called by the user but I'm not sure how you plan on the user interacting with the game so can't explain much more...

Answer (score 1):

For starters you're probably going to want to keep track of both the minimum (probably 0), maximum, and current values of each of your properties. From there you'll just be manipulating the current value, e.g.

```
function Pet(name){
    this.name = name;

    this.maxHealth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    this.currentHealth = this.maxHealth;

    this.maxHappiness = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    this.currentHappiness = this.maxHappiness;

    this.maxHunger = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    this.currentHunger = 0;

    this.feed = function(amount = 1) {
        if (amount > this.currentHunger) {
            this.currentHunger = 0;
        } else {
            this.currentHunger -= amount;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has prototype-based inheritance. When you do something like `pet1.something`, it looks at the pet1 instance to see if it has a property called `something`. If it doesn't, it looks at the objet's prototype to see if it has a propety called `something`. If it doesn't, it checks the prototype's prototype, and so on.

The smart way to give objects methods just like you would in Class-based object programming is to give methods to the prototype.

```
Pet.prototype.feed = function() {
  this.nutrition += 20;
}; //note the semicolumn
```

If you declare functions within the constructor instead, each pet will have its own copy of each function, which takes memory for no reason. There are special cases where it might be useful, but in your case, stick to the prototype way.

Perhaps a better `feed` function would make sure you don't overfeed the pet.

```
Pet.prototype.feed = function() {
    this.nutrition += 20;
    if(this.nutrition > 100) {
       this.health -= 10;
       this.nutrition = 100;
       this.say("I ate too much :S");
    }
};
```

You might want to store maximum and minimum values for your different stats. For example, if any value gets to 0, the pet dies, but if the pet's energy gets below 10 it'll fall asleep and if its hunger or mood gets below 10 its health will be affected, and so on. The opposite can be true, a pet which eats too much might get sick.

Those constants which tell what values are important can be kept in the constructor function itself. You might want to store multiple values in a sub-object for each, and if the value is below that constant, then your pet might ask you for food, sleep, etc.

```
Pet.maxAny = 100;
Pet.hungerCaps = {good: 80, ok: 50, need: 30, bad: 20};
Pet.sleepCaps = {good: 50, ok: 40, need: 30, bad: 20};
Pet.moodCaps = {good: 80, ok: 60, need: 40, bad: 30};
```

Then you could make a function which lowers all stats over time. I'll let you think about this for a while :)

Comment: @Nappstir I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking, but you shouldn't make lassy a blank object. I can't really do more than this for you, but try reading the lessons on Mozilla Developper Network.

Comment: NVM on last comment. I made some adjustments and was able to get my `feed` function to work. However, if you look above, I cant seem to find a good approach with `show`.